# javascript batch add keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, addition

I want to set multiple keys of array in javascript ,

but code like this was so ugly. but only this can work right.

```html
var listData = [];
listData['today'] = [];
listData['data1'] = [];
listData['data2'] = [];
listData['data3'] = [];
listData['data4'] = [];
listData['data5'] = [];
listData['data6'] = [];
listData['data6'] = [];
```

i try this to init array

```html
function initArray(arr, keys, defaultValue) {
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        delete arr[key];
        arr[key] = defaultValue;

    }
    return arr;
}
```

But after setting the array,

i put data in it by 
listData['data1'].push(datalist[i].num)
listData['data2'].push(datalist[i].num)
.
 returns all the same data1  and data2 in array.

hope someone can help about this batch add keys to array.

Comment: An array doesn't generally have named keys like `data1`, but just numeric indexes

Comment: You're looking for an _object_ `listData = {}`

Comment: @adeneo: Well, they do, if you add them, because standard arrays are objects... But yes, the OP probably wants a non-array object (or to use the array as an array).

Comment: @ jeri - I'm sorry, I cannot make out what you're asking here. Can you please explain what you're looking to do more clearly?

Comment: I want to use arr['data1']=aksdfs; and this array keys may be lots of 。like arr['data1'],arr['data2'].....，i want to batch set it to array.just as i say . i want to batch add keys to some array。

Comment: You can do so using object as Jeremy commented

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - well, yes, you can add properties to arrays because they are objects as well, but those properties won't really be part of the "array-part", i.e. the `length` won't be updated, and the OP's `for` loop will fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying this push method.

```
var listData = [];
var keys = [ 'today', 'data', 'daata' ]; 
initObject(keys);

function initObject(params) {
    for (i=0; i<params.length; i++) {
        var x = params[i]
        listData.push(x)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an object instead of an array:

```
var listData = {};
var keys = ['today', 'data1', 'data2'];

function initObject(obj, keys, defaultValue) {
  keys.forEach(key => {
    obj[key] = [];
  })
  return obj;
}

console.log(initObject(listData, keys, []));
```